# Xcode tab bar items are not visible in storyboard

Tags: xcode, uitabbarcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I have a Tab Bar Controller in a storyboard and I want to rearrange the items but I can't see any of the items.  When I run it they display without a problem but they aren't visible in the storyboard.  I am using XCode 6.1.1.  Has anyone run into this?

[image: Tab bar with tabs missing]

Comment: Same here. Most likely an Xcode bug.

Comment: @Brian Kalski  i too facing same problem. Please let me know if u got something

Comment: Yeah, me too. I was fiddling around with this and it turns out that you can actually drag it around by dragging invisible tabs. But I still want to see them and double click the name to edit them!!!

Comment: I think it is a bug.  If I open a new project and add a tab bar controller immediately I don't see it.  It may be fixed in the newest XCode version.

Comment: I'm also facing this issue. It really looks like an Xcode bug, as in my case it also appears in a completely clean project, made just to test this feature. However it is not written in the "Known issues" for latest Xcode release. So I'm not sure if it's worth to file a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I was using "Custom" tab bar items. The image for my custom tab bar item was defined only for one tab. And in this case tab bar items were not shown in the main tab bar controller. After adding some temporary images to every tab bar item I'm able to see them correctly in the main tab bar controller.

Definitely an Xcode bug.

Answer (score -1):

I too ran into this problem for a moment and was able to overcome it by:

1) check any of the tab bar emblems (the destination emblems)

2) if there is a selected image, remove it

3) reload xcode

I don't know why this worked or why it was a problem in the first place, but I hope this helps.